# vhost.conf and general understanding

Tags: installation, error-templates

I am new to craft CMS and installed it in an Amazon EC2 instance via Composer.
This worked.
My vhost.conf looks like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName craft.example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/viacraft/www-craft-test
ServerAdmin tristanvii@example.com
ErrorLog /var/www/vhosts/logs/error_log_viacraft
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/viacraft/www-craft-test>
        AllowOverride All
</Directory>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =craft.viainfo.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

Database setup worked and passed.
Then according to the manual I called

https://craft.example.com/index.php?p=admin/install

which leads to an File not found error.

Then I put a hello.php in /var/www/vhosts/viacraft/www-craft-test but https://craft.example.com/hello.php did not worked which I did not understand.
Then I put the hello.php in /var/www/vhosts/viacraft **and it worked** which is strange because the web directory in the vhost.conf is /var/www/vhosts/viacraft/www-craft-test **and not** /var/www/vhosts/viacraft/

Any ideas to this behaviour?

Then I managed to start the whole thing by entering

https://craft.example.com/www-craft-test/admin/dashboard

Why do I have to enter my webfolder www-craft-test in the path to call the dashboard???

I made my first entry - a blog and when I press Preview the following page is called

https://craft.example.com/www-craft-test/admin/entries/blog/17-my-first-blog

with the error

```
Page Not Found
Template not found: blog/_entry
```

I am **not** in development mode.

Settings/Site This site has its own base URL is UNCHECKED

This is my .htaccess in the www-craft-test folder

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  # Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

In the templates folder there is still the original index.twig file.

A bit confused, happy to get some helpful ideas?

Thanks

Tristan

Answer (score 1):

Your virtual hosting config looks good to me.  However, how are you running SSL?

You've only shown the port 80 / non-SSL config and it shows a redirect to https so the `DocumentRoot` probably differs between port 80 and 443 versions vhost stanzas.

Make sure `DocumentRoot` is the same in both places and you should be able to load up Craft without the www-craft-test prefix.